# Why factory bean needs non static method in spring IOC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, static, javabeans

A factory method of a Bean class should be static whereas a factory methods of a bean present in a factory class should be non static.

Spring IOC throws exceptions if this requirement is not fulfilled.

I am clear on why we need static factory method for a bean as to instantiate a bean using method, it needs to be static.

But why we needs non static method for a factory bean.

Answer (score 0):

`FactoryBean` is the name of an *interface* which declares the method `getObject()`. The point of any interface is the same as this one: polymorphism. What would be the point of obtaining an instance of `FactoryBean` if you were to call some static method?

I am also quite unclear on what you may mean by "Spring throws exceptions if this requirement is not fulfilled". The *Java compiler* produces a compilation error if you declare a class implementing `FactoryBean` but do not implement its methods.

Comment: Sorry @marko but I am asking with reference to Spring framework. While creating a bean we get option in spring IDE to create a bean it by factory-method or factory-bean

Comment: `FactoryBean` is Spring's interface so I'm not sure what else you might mean.

Comment: If you mean this: `<bean id="x" factory-bean="facBean" factory-method="getX"/>` then clearly, if you specify an *instance* (which is what the factory bean is), Spring wants an *instance method* to call on it.